# I locked myself out of garage, how can I get back in?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

I locked myself out of the garage (Craftsman/Liftmaster 315).  I used the wall control to put the door down, but I had accidentally activated "vacation mode."  The remote control will not let me in now.  Is there a way I can still get in?  (There are no alternative doors).

Comment: Is there really no other door into this garage?   If there is a door that’s locked can you pull the hinge pins?

Comment: does the door have a window?

Comment: once you get in, the next step is to install a secondary control panel in your house

Comment: or a key operated switch on the garage wall, I'm assuming the house is not connected to the garage, because usually there's a door if it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can reach over the top of the door with a stiff wire (eg: 1/4" or 3/8" reinforcing bar) and release the emergency release? (then just lift the door manually)

Maybe you can drill though the wall behind the wall control and access the wires?

maybe you can drill through the door in the center near the top and activate the release with a metal rod

Comment: This is a fairly standard way for burglars to get into houses with automatic garage doors. There's usually _some_ amount of flex at the top of the door, often enough to get an arm through (although beware they don't care if they damage the door), and definitely enough to get a bent coat-hanger through.